# How to tell xargs which argument to choose ?

Tags: command-line, pipe, xargs

When xargs redirects the first commands output into the second command's argument and there is no choice about which argument for which element of the output, then there is only one way, for instance:

```
ls | xargs file  # there are as many arguments as files in the listing,
                 # but the user does not have too choose himself
```

now if there is a need for choice:

```
ls | xargs file | grep image | xargs mv.....   # here the user has to 
                                               # deal  with two arguments of mv, first for source second for destination, suppose your destination argument is set already by yourself and you have to put the output into the source argument.
```

**How do you tell xargs to redirect the standard output of the first command into the argument of your choice of the second command ?**

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `-I` to define a place-holder which will be replaced with each value of the arguments fed to `xargs`. For example,

```
ls -1 | xargs -I '{}' echo '{}'
```

will call `echo` once per line from `ls`'s output. You'll often see `'{}'` used, presumably because it's the same as `find`'s place-holder.

In your case, you also need to pre-process `file`'s output to extract the matching file names; since there's a `grep` in there we can just use `awk` to do both, and simplify the `file` invocation as well:

```
file * | awk -F: '/image/ { print $1 }' | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' destination
```

If you've got GNU `mv` you could just use `-t` to pass multiple source files:

```
file * | awk -F: '/image/ { print $1 }' | xargs mv -t destination
```

Comment: Most underrated answer on stack overflow.